# In Python how to mark all collections in the outliner as assets?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of collections in my outliner and I would like to programmatically mark all of these collections as assets.
Anyone has an idea?

Many thanks for your help.

Best regards

Marc

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy


for coll in bpy.context.scene.collection.children:
    coll.asset_mark()
```